# Noob here. Why doesn't my image link to my html or get interpreted by browser?

Tags: html

I'm using "TextEdit" on mac. I have already formatted my text to plain text. I've already tried to make an absolute path, I've tried changing the name several times, I tried changing the location of the files and the location of the parent folder. The file does open on a web browser on it's  own

[image: finder and code]]

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <img src="1.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try closing the img tag like this <img src="1.png" />

Comment: @KirkBeard I typed it all out in an edit, and fixed the image :)

Comment: @KirkBeard Yeah, I'm really bored :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this code instead.

```
<img src="1.png">
```

The problem seems to be with the quotation marks.
Here is a link to a similar question -
 [Why are some of my HTML internal links working and others not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649114/why-are-some-of-my-html-internal-links-working-and-others-not?rq=1)

Apparently, you have **Smart quotes**. TextEdit is converting your double quotes to smart quotes, which happens when TextEdit is in plain mode. Go to **Edit** > **Substitutions** in TextEdit and make sure **Smart Quotes** is unchecked.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 1):

having the image tag close and alt text is best practice.

```
<img src="1.png" alt="image one"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to replace the quotes around "1.png" with plain quotes instead of typographical quotes. i.e. just `src="1.png"`

Second, you should add a file extension to your html page file, like `Newsite.html` instead of just `Newsite`